# Confine all processing inside ROI

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing

How do I confine this code (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) to happen only inside the ROI.

Similar to this one wherein a visible rectangle is specified and any vehicles that enter it are the only ones that are processed: 
 [image]

(Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPmG30byCyc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html

As stated here, define your region, create a binary mask and mask your original image with it, as to only leave a region of interest.

Comment: So it's like the binary mask is to be glued with the original image. Then all the processing from the link I posted above would be performed only in that binary mask?

Comment: Yeah, so assuming your image is RGB (3 channels), you have to do the following image_to_create = original_image .* repmat(mask_you_created, [1,1,3]) however there are a couple of different ways you could do it

Comment: Roipoly outputs a binary mask with pixel values of 1 for the area you chose. Let's say I'd set the pedestrian lane as my ROI using roipoly. So the output is the pixels in the pedestrian lane area are 1s then 0s for the rest of the pixels. Considering this, how then would I process the moving objects inside the ROI (the tutorial I posted) if all the pixels inside that region are 1s already?

Comment: You would have to do a bitwise and (bitand) operation between the mask output by roipoly and the original image.

Comment: Ohhh right bitand! Do you know some matlab functions that performs that?

Comment: It can be found here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html

Comment: okay then its output would be the binary mask to perform the next step on? (vision.blobAnalysis for example)

Comment: Hey man when mathworks.com/help says: outputs a "binary mask", is it a  a mxn matrix of 1s and 0s? Since bitand returns a matrix.

Comment: Yes it is, with 1s being in the region you want